# SQL query is not being executed in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SQL query and I want to execute it in C# on a button click, but when I click the 
button the database is not being affected:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MedTab (MedID,MedName,Manf,MedProd,MedExp,TimeLeft,InStock) VALUES (4,'sdfs','sdfsd','sdfsdf','sdfsdf','sdfsd',33);";
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where is the command executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you want is this:

```
String ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True";
String sql = "INSERT INTO MedTab (MedID,MedName,Manf,MedProd,MedExp,TimeLeft,InStock) VALUES (4,'sdfs','sdfsd','sdfsdf','sdfsdf','sdfsd',33);";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
  con.Open();

  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Is good to add that with the using in the SqlConnection, the connection will close automatically after the ExecuteNonQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Add `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` after setting the command text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually execute the query (try `ExecuteNonQuery`).

You're currently opening a connection, setting the statement to execute, then just closing the connection.